# Mapping over data with dynamic images

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, if-statement

So I have the following react component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

/// Get out static assets
import logo1 from '../images/scaffold/logo1.svg';
import logo2 from '../images/scaffold/logo2.svg';
import logo3 from '../images/scaffold/logo3.svg';
import logo4 from '../images/scaffold/logo4.svg';
import logo5 from '../images/scaffold/logo5.svg';
import logo6 from '../images/scaffold/logo6.svg';
import logo7 from '../images/scaffold/logo7.svg';

const Links = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {Object.keys(props.link).map(i => (
      <a key={i} href={props.link[i]}
      target="_blank">
      <div className="release-action">
      <div className="release-distro-logo">
      <img src={logo1}/>
      </div>
      <span>Action1</span>
      </div>
      </a>
    ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Links;
```

I would like to change the **logo** and the **action** text based on the data that comes in from **props**. Is it possible to use the key of the value pair in an if statement to do this? So for example, if the key was **link2** then **logo2** would be used and the span would change to **Action2** basically the logos would visually present the link and the link URL would be used in the link src.

the links are loaded via json and pushed via props to the component

```
"isbn" : "3049204",
"author" : "author name",
"links": {
    "link1": "https://www.google.com",
    "link2": "https://www.yahoo.com",
    "link3": "https://www.facebook.com",
    "link4": "https://www.twitter.com",
    "link5": "https://www.instagram.com",
    "link6": "https://www.gmail.com"
  },
"cta" : "buy now"
```

Comment: Use Object.entries

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create an object containing all the available images like this:

```
const logos = {
 link1: logo1,
 link2: logo2,
 // ...
};
```

And then in React

```
const Links = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {Object.keys(props.link).map(i => (
      <a key={i} href={props.link[i]}
      target="_blank">
      <div className="release-action">
      <div className="release-distro-logo">
      <img src={logos[i]}/>
      </div>
      <span>Action1</span>
      </div>
      </a>
    ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: the thing is the logos should match the key or value of the props / data. the above solution means that the links and logos always have to be in the correct order for the images to match the links.. right ?

Comment: hmm.. i'm still not understanding the above. how are you matching the logo with the correct link when the links are provided via json and passed by props ? i've updated the data example as the list of links comes from a loaded json

Comment: i'm going to provide the logos for the links in the json and do it that way rather than trying to conditionally do it in the app, thanks for the help!